# How to synchronize between transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking

I have the following stored procedure. It is meant to get a name. If the name exists in a table it returns its corresponding ID. If it doesn't exist yet, it creates a new ID, and adds it to the table with the new ID.

The problem is that when I run this on multiple threads which use the same name (not yet in the table) I sometimes get the name entered several times, with subsequent IDs.

What I would like is for the transactions to block while another transaction is running, so that the name only gets in the database once.

Is there an isolation level or select hint I should be using? Is there another way to do this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_createID] 
@name varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRAN
    DECLARE @id as int
    SELECT @id=Id FROM MyTbl WHERE name=@name
    IF @id IS NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE idGeneratorTbl SET lastkey=lastkey+1
        SELECT @id=lastKey FROM idGeneratorTbl
        INSERT INTO MyTbl VALUES(@id, @name)
    END
    SELECT @id
COMMIT          
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the procs should be on the same transaction to achieve what  you want.

You can achieve that by removing the transaction control in the [sp_generateNewId] proc.

FYI, you don’t need to worry about keys generation, why don’t you just create an IDENTITY field

Comment: I moved the sp_generateNewId code into the sp_createID code, to remove the extra transaction control. Unfortunately, this does not help.

I am aware of the IDENTITY field. We use it in new tables, but these are old tables that have been with our product for many years, and I would rather not change them at this point.

Comment: thats weird, I think that the transaction is releasing the lock on the MyTbl table after it is read, not after the transaction is commited. try doing "SELECT @id=Id FROM MyTbl WHERE name=@name" with TABLOCKX or XLOCK See the explanation on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Comment: @Shahar These are nested transactions. Inner commit does not commit at all, so all the locks are held until outer commit.

Comment: Looks like the TABLOCKX hint gets the job done, even if I go back to separate procedures with nested transactions (in line with what Nikola says).

Comment: very good. It makes sense because the lock wont let any other transaction to access the table to re-insert the name. Also, please remember to vote and mark as answer